# How to sum certain rows in a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset that looks at number of open positions and request by manasger. I want to get the sum of only three columns.

```
PostingID      Job            ManagerID       Manager       Approvals  Request  Deny
   101      Sales Advisor        123          John Doe          1        0        0
   102      Sales Advisor        123          John Doe          0        0        1
   103      Sales Advisor        123          John Doe          1        0        0
   105      Tech Consultant      374          Mary Sue          0        1        0
   107      Tech Consultant      374          Mary Sue          0        1        0
```

What I want is to have those approvals, request and Denies all summed and grouped by ID.
Here is the output I would like:

```
ManagerID    Manager   Approvals  Request    Deny 
   123       John Doe      2         0         1
   374       Mary Sue      0         2         0
```

What would be the best approach for this.